# How to delete pdf files created by itext in the same java project?

Tags: java, file-io

I'm trying to delete a pdf file from one of the packages of a java application created by itext in some other other package of same application

I've used the following codes but i'm getting some error in both the cases...

```
File existing = new File(RESULT);
existing.deleteOnExit();

src = Paths.get(RESULT);
try {
    existing.
    Files.deleteIfExists(src);
} catch (IOException ex){}*/
```

Comment: Define "some error". I'm pretty sure the files are in use, but you'll have to be more specific if you want an answer.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException

Comment: Then it's not an iText problem, but a problem similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411463/java-nio-file-filealreadyexistsexception-how-to-resolve-this-in-java7

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The little code snippet you added is not even compilable. Please fix this. Also, a complete stacktrace (with the exception, its message, and a pointer to the line where it's thrown) would be necessary for you to get any useful help.